# How do I funnel streaming data into another process (Twitter >> MIDI >> Synthesis)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, stream, midi

I'm trying to stream Twitter data that takes the letter of every tweet and then funnels that data into a process that would assign a midi output variable to it (e.g., the letter 'a' = Middle C = MIDI number 60).

I can print the letters one by one down the terminal in Ubuntu, but I need to the letter to correspond to a MIDI note and then output to something else. Any help would be great to help me learn this. I'm using Python 2.7.

NOTE: I'm trying to stream the data, *not* output the data to a MIDI file (I am open to that, though).

```
class listener(StreamListener):
    def on_data (self, data):
        tweet = data.split(',"text":"')[1].split('","source')[0]
        for letters in tweet:
            number = ord(letters)
            print (letters, number)

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["sad"])
```

Comment: what other processes are you going to use to receive the notes/text?

Comment: That's what I'm asking. I'm not sure what I would need to do to set that up.

Comment: Do you have a synthesizer?

Comment: @AntonioNogueras I think this is too broad to be answerable then, as the methods available for transferring data will depend on the software. You should familiarize yourself with the available audio software, pick what you need and *then* worry about getting the data there. If you're doing this in linux, the [linux audio wiki](http://wiki.linuxaudio.org/wiki/start) is a great place to get started.

Comment: I have a synth, and I have the DAW (Ableton) for which I could potentially pip this date through. I just need to know what I need to do listen at the incoming data. The data stream works, I currently have it printing each letter of each tweet 1 by 1.